# Log pages that are redirecting to my page

Tags: php

I have a page on Domain A that is the target of redirects from many pages, not necessarily on Domain A.

On the page, I'd like to display something like:

"http://somedomain.com/somepage is not available"

HTTP referrer doesn't quite do it.  Is there another standard header that I could use to get this information?

Comment: [http is a stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), so no.

Answer (score 0):

ALL headers are possibly spoofed, so you'll never find reliable information in ANY of them.

If you have control over all the domains that get redirected, do the logging there. If they're on the same server, you shoudl consider internal redirects instead of external ones (internal like "the server juist outputs some other page instead of the one that was requested, browser doesn't notice").
But to tell you more here, we'd really need some more info. Also, the question might better fit into [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).